# Are questions about availability of 3D models on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question ([Is there any public and reasonably accurate 3D scan from a Cray-2 computer?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5699/is-there-any-public-and-reasonably-accurate-3d-scan-from-a-cray-2-computer)) about where to find (if there is any, because I tried and there seems not to be) a 3D model of a specific object I could use as a starting point for printable model and printable parts and it was flagged as off-topic and closed. Has this type of question proved to be troublesome in the past?

Answer (score 2):

This topic is actually up for debate *possibly*. I don't personally know if this sort of question has been actually *troublesome*. I remember your question well and whilst it didn't fit into the scope *as it is currently defined*, it seemed (IMHO) a reasonable question nevertheless. It was unfortunate that you did not get a suitable answer before your question was closed.

I have include this question in the new meta post about what should and shouldn't be on-topic, [Game plan - What is on-topic?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/game-plan-what-is-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

mostly this is an off-topic question, as per [question rules - click](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

That means your question is not about solving a technical problem.